# Does a Google Wave have a Url?

Tags: url, google-wave

I think I get Google Wave, at this stage. I've seen how it can be a useful tool at work, among a small number of people working on a specific project.

What I want to know, given that it's web-based, is: does a wave have a canonical URL?

If so, are there querystring parameters that I might want to set to set the state of the wave? If I send someone a link to a wave in an email, what do I need to know about them to be sure that they will actually be able to see that wave?

Comment: How is this "not computer related"?  That's just asinine.

Comment: Well, I want to use this site, but this is just silly. I guess I should have specified that I was referring to the Google Wave that you use on a computer, not the other ones. Oh well.

Comment: I only just noticed this: "This question is very far afield from software". Really? Google Wave is very far afield from software? Wow! Ok.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the address bar has the wave's canonical link.  If you email it to an invited participant, it will be the selected wave when they start.  If they have not been added to it, they get "You are not a participant in this wave."

Comment: Well, I can see that one of my (public) waves has the link: https://wave.google.com/wave/#restored:wave:googlewave.com!w%252BNMJ9N68LD.1. But is that the fixed, canonical link? That "#restored" implies to me some sort of state that may be only temporary